# When I save any typescript files in vscode. All edited single quotes turns into double quotes

Tags: angular

```
'@Component({
  selector: "message-list",
  templateUrl: "./message-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./message-list.component.css"],'
```

What setting do I need to do when you save the file like selector:

```
 'message-list';
import { MessageVM } from "../message-section/message.vm" to import { MessageVM } from '../message-section/message.vm'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be related with the formatter, if you are using [prettier formatter](https://prettier.io/) you can add .prettierrc file in the root of your project with the following configuration

```
{
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't include `printWidth` and `tabWidth` in the answer as they don't relate to the question in any way, and will likely lead to some unexpected results.

Comment: Yes that is true, I already removed these properties of the example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps in order to disable that feature from the vscode. (If you have already installed the  Prettier plugin with vscode )

File > Preferences > Settings

- Then in the search bar search for `singleQuote`.
- Then you can see a configuration like `Prettier:Single Quote`
- Untick that.

So that it will never replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Prettier extension, see the other answers. If you don't have Prettier, then this should help:

Option 1 - JSON config:

1. Open the settings JSON file `(Command/Control + Shift + P)` > `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
2. Add the following: `"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"`

Option 2 - UI config:

1. Open the settings UI `(Command/Control + Shift + P)` > `Prefrences: Open Settings (UI)`
2. Search for "typescript quote style" and set the value to `single`